# OpenCV unable to read video from MJPEG stream

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I'm trying to open an mjpeg stream with VideoCapture in OpenCV2
But whenever I try to read a frame I get the following error thrown:
`[mjpeg @ 0x10f4d20] unable to decode APP fields: Invalid data found when processing input`

I can watch the stream without issues in the browser. I also tried the typical suggestion of adding a dummy parameter like `?type=.mjpg` but no luck.

This is how I open the stream:

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://localhost:8000/camera/mjpeg?type=.mjpg")
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, image = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow("Result", image)
```

Comment: Your question appears to be a list of statements. What *exactly* is your question? Is it "Why am I getting this error message?" or "What does this error message mean?", or is it "If I am getting this error message, why can I successfully watch the stream in the browser?", or is it "Does this error message matter?" Or is it "Why do the other people posting answers not get the same error message as myself?" Or perhaps you have a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing exactly this (Python 3.7) and it is working. I have a Raspberry Pi 4 sending out a stream. On the same network, my MacBook is running the following code.

```
# Open a URL stream
stream = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.50.1:8080/stream.mjpg')
while ( stream.isOpened() ):
    # Read a frame from the stream
    ret, img = stream.read()
    if ret: # ret == True if stream.read() was successful
        cv2.imshow('Video Stream Monitor', img)
```

So I'm not sure what you were doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use urllib for reading that

```
import cv2
import urllib.request
import numpy as np

stream = urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8000/camera/mjpeg?type=.mjpg')
bytes = b''
while True:
    bytes += stream.read(1024)
    a = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd8') #frame starting 
    b = bytes.find(b'\xff\xd9') #frame ending
    if a != -1 and b != -1:
        jpg = bytes[a:b+2]
        bytes = bytes[b+2:]
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('image', img)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

Comment: running this yields ` bytes += stream.read(1024)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
`

Comment: sorry add b when define bytes like bytes = b''

Comment: Now its stuck at `    a = bytes.find('\xff\xd8') #frame starting 
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'` :)

Comment: idk what is going on first version code works well for me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mjpeg streamer, to access to the stream use

```
stream = opencv.VideoCapture('http://localhost:8080/?action=stream')
```

or

```
stream = opencv.VideoCapture('http://XX.XX.XX.XX:8080/?action=stream')
```